# C# Data Transformation on Single Object

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am trying to wondering if there is a way to transform a method result into a new object in a single line, as is possible when using a List, Linq, and Lambda expressions.

Example using lists:

```cs
List<int> ints = GetListOfInts();
List<anotherClass> = ints.Select(x => new anotherClass(){ memberVariable = x }).ToList();
```

Through this,  I can map a list of type A to a list of type B.

I want to do this on a single object, not a list. Here is what I am intending:

```cs
// GetObjectA returns an instance of ObjectA
ObjectA objectA = GetObjectA();

// Here, GetOjbectA's result is mapped to an instance of ObjectB
ObjectB objectB = (GetObjectA() x => new ObjectB(){ memberVariable = x });
```

This is just pseuodocode, and I know it will not compile or work. Is this type of transformation currently possible in C#?

I know I can use mappers, custom methods, etc., but I want to know if it is possible through lamba expressions as it is with lists.

Comment: Instead of ToList use FirstOrDefault() ?

Comment: @Mike That requires a collection. OP: no, that's not possible with LINQ, LINQ is for collections. Not sure what you are after

Comment: The object being transformed isn't a list, so that option isn't available. In my case, I am using DTOs.

Comment: LINQ is just extension methods on collection types.  You can create extension methods (or regular methods) on your types as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// GetObjectA returns an instance of ObjectA
ObjectA objectA = GetObjectA();

// Here, GetOjbectA's result is mapped to an instance of ObjectB
ObjectB objectB = new[]{ GetObjectA() }.Select(x => new ObjectB(){ memberVariable = x }).First();
```

Not nice, but should work.

However, if it's really that specific code, you could just do

```
ObjectB objectB = new ObjectB(){ memberVariable = GetObjectA() };
```

If you want it encapsulated nicely, you could write something like this:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static TOutput Transform<TInput, TOutput>(this TInput input, Func<TInput, TOutput> transform)
    {
        return transform(input);
    }
}
```

and use it like that:

```
// GetObjectA returns an instance of ObjectA
ObjectA objectA = GetObjectA();

// Here, GetOjbectA's result is mapped to an instance of ObjectB
ObjectB objectB = GetObjectA().Transform(x => new ObjectB(){ memberVariable = x });
```

Comment: That's the only solution I have come up with as well. I was just hoping there was a way to do it without creating a collection. It's not really for a specific situation, I was just thinking it could be useful when creating / morphing DTOs. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Just saw your update. That's a great solution for me. Thank you! I'll mark it.

Comment: Tested the function and it works perfectly. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again.